# Uma lista para receber 20 números inteiros e armazenar em uma lista e imprimir o maior elemento da lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input("digite o número : ")
I=0
For i in lista:
 lista[i].append(input("digite o número"
 I+=1
else:
 Print("lista cheia")
```

Sou novo em Programação e não consigo implantar o que o questionário quer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para obter o maior valor em uma lista de números, existe a função nativa [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print("Maior número da lista é:", max(numeros))
```

Retorna a mensagem:

```
Maior número da lista é: 5
```

Para gerar esta lista dinamicamente através da entrada do usuário, em Python, o mais fácil é utilizar [compreensão de listas](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
numeros = [int(input("Número: ")) for i in range(20)]
```

A linha de código acima pode ser melhor compeendida com um trecho de código semelhante, porém não análogo:

```
numeros = []
for i in range(20):
    numeros.append(int(input("Número: ")))
```

O código final ficaria:

```
numeros = [int(input("Número: ")) for i in range(20)]
print("Maior número da lista é:", max(numeros))
```

> Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/HsxA/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1
lista = []
print('Digite 20 números.')
while x <= 20:
    n = int(input('Digite um número: [ %s ]: '%x))
    lista.append(n)
    x += 1
print('O maior valor é:',max(lista))
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = []

while len(lista)+1 <= 20:
 lista.append(int(input("Digite um número: ")))

print ("O maior valor é: ", max(lista))
```

Comment: Por favor, colabore com a qualidade do conteúdo da comunidade elaborando melhor sua resposta. Respostas muito curtas dificilmente serão suficientemente claras para acrescentar algo à discussão. Se sua resposta é baseada em alguma função ou característica da linguagem/ferramenta, faça a ligação com a documentação oficial ou material confiável que sustente sua resposta. Buscar perguntas semelhantes na comunidade também pode ser interessante para indicar outras abordagens do problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podemos resolver esta questão desta forma:

```
maior = max([x for x in input('Digite os valores: ').split()])
print(f'O maior número da lista é: {maior}')
```

Quando executamos este código recebemos a seguinte mensagem: `Digite os valores:` . Neste momento devemos digitar todos os valores, na mesma linha, separados por um só espaço e pressionar enter.